# How can I add a URL to the download manager in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome

I've been working on an extension that checks for certain URLs in page content and lets the user put a button to automatically put these into the download manager. I've gotten everything I need, but how do I actually tell Chrome to put the URL into the download queue?

Comment: I've submitted this to the (members only - review only) Google Group: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/5857b0fb6f39b48e#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, its not supported yet. There are no extensions for Chrome download manager.

Comment: Would creating a new window do the trick if the file-type is downloadable?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that, that would be a nice neat trick.